# Ошибка: TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

Я пытаюсь сделать алгоритм на python, определяющий написанные от руки английские буквы, но при попытке обучения появляется ошибка.
Мой код:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as knc

abc_train = pd.read_csv("alphabet.csv")

columns = ["let"]
for i in range(784):
    columns.append(f"px_{i+1}")
abc_train.columns = columns
label_name = abc_train["let"].values
let_train = abc_train.values[:, 1:]
pict_train = let_train.reshape(372450 , 28, 28)
knc = knc.fit( pict_train, label_name)
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-5c26061e5501> in <module>
----> 1 knc = knc.fit( pict_train[1:14325], label_name)

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Что я делаю не так? Как я могу решить эту проблему / ошибку ?
Может ли это быть из-за того, что в датасете не указан верный вывод?

Comment: Странная ошибка, вроде бы все правильно у вас: http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.fit

Comment: Если верить документации https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.fit ну и самой ошибке, которая вам выводится: не хватает параметра "y".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы не создали объект класса `KNeighborsClassifier`, а использовали метод **класса** `KNeighborsClassifier.fit()`.

Попробуйте так:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knc = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)

...

knc.fit(pict_train, label_name)
```

PS @gil9red отлично дополнил ответ в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962854/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-typeerror-fit-missing-1-required-positional-argument-y/962874?noredirect=1#comment1612042_962874):

> в питоне у методов объекта есть первый, неочевидный параметр `self`, в
>   который кладется ссылка на объект, что метод вызвал и в случае вызова
>   метода классом (а не объектом), в тот параметр `self` попал объект
>   `pict_train`, а `label_name`, соответственно, попал в `X`, поэтому и
>   ругается на `y`?

Comment: `вы не создали объект класса KNeighborsClassifier`, *рукалицо* вот это я проглядел у автора вопроса :)

Comment: @gil9red, я тоже не сразу заметил...

Comment: Кст, мб указать в ответе, что в питоне у методов объекта есть первый, неочевидный параметр `self`, в который кладется ссылка на объект, что метод вызвал и в случаи вызова метода классом (а не объектом), в тот параметр self попал объект pict_train, а label_name, соответственно, попал в X, поэтому и ругается на y?

Comment: @gil9red, отличная идея! Оформите как ответ? :)

Comment: Не думаю, лучше в ваш ответ добавить, например как `PS.`, или пусть останется в моем комментарии

Comment: @gil9red, добавил как PS ;)